# Spark SQL - Convert SHA1 to BIGINT

Tags: apache-spark-sql, databricks

I've been tasked with moving a lot of T-SQL into Spark (Databricks). The procedures I'm converting are creating surrogate keys in a somewhat typical manner for BI. What I'm trying to figure out the Spark equivalent to the following T-SQL:

```
select convert(bigint,hashbytes('sha1', N'570'))
-- Returns: -1488953326447475322
```

In Spark using SQL I can get the same hashbytes by doing:

```
select sha1(encode('570', 'UTF-16LE'))
--2c14de511f01a8abec0a4f15eb562cd6a1f64586 in Spark
--0x2C14DE511F01A8ABEC0A4F15EB562CD6A1F64586 in T-SQL
```

What I'm struggling to figure out is how to convert the returned hash into a bigint. I know that SHA1 is a 16 byte result and bigint is only 8 bytes, so there is truncation going on, but when trying to force this truncation using CONV like I've seen suggested I don't get close to the results I'm after.

```
select conv(substring(sha1(encode('570', 'UTF-16LE')), 0, 16), 16, 10)
--Returns: 3176408077196961963
```

Has anyone accomplished this?

Comment: Using SparkSQL, by reverse-engineer your output: `select conv(-1488953326447475322,10,16)` --> _EB562CD6A1F64586_ which is the last 16-chars of sha1() output, so I guess you can try: `spark.sql("select conv(right(sha1(encode('570', 'UTF-16LE')),16),16,-10)")`.

Comment: @jxc this whole time I was beating my head against my keyboard not noticing it was the last 16 chars while I was trying to accomplish it using the first 16. Thank you!

Comment: Isn't sha1 a 160bit / 20 bytes / 40 hexadecimal digits? [Source](https://codesigningstore.com/hash-algorithm-comparison)

Answer (score 0):

select hash(sha1(encode('570', 'UTF-16LE')))

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).